# Python pandas: assert_frame_equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 df's (call them bdf and cdf) to compare to verify that their contents are equal. So i used

```
pd.util.testing.assert_frame_equal(bdf, cdf, check_dtype=False, check_like=True, check_exact=True)
```

to do the comparison. However, the function asserted a difference in a column that i didn't expect:

```
DataFrame.iloc[:, 70] are different

DataFrame.iloc[:, 70] values are different (100.0 %)
[left]:  [201801300040150000014217, 201801300040150000014217, 201801300040150000013737, 201801290040150000019605, 201801300040150000076982, 201801300040150000136588, 201801300040150000242399, 201801300040150000293800, 201801300040150000293801, 201801290040150000128792, 201801300040150000367067, 201801300040150000367770, 201801300040150000369255, 201801260040150000097789, 0, 0, 201801290040150000145140, 0, 201801290040150000145184, 201801290040150000145190, 201801290040150000145198, 201801290040150000145206, 201801290040150000145214, 201801290040150000145222, 0, 0, 201801290040150000145245, 201801290040150000145254, 201801290040150000145263, 201801290040150000145271, 201801290040150000145278, 201801290040150000145286, 201801290040150000145297, 201801290040150000145309, 201801290040150000145318, 201801290040150000145327, 201801290040150000149263, 201801290040150000149264, 201801300040150000433569, 201801290040150000156348, 201801290040150000161046, 201801290040150000161050, 201801290040150000165445, 0, 201801290040150000165456, 201801290040150000165472, 0, 0, 201801290040150000165496, 0, 0, 201801290040150000165520, 0, 0, 0, 201801290040150000165556, 0, 201801260040150000129418]
[right]: [201801300040150000014217, 201801300040150000014217, 201801300040150000013737, 201801290040150000019605, 201801300040150000076982, 201801300040150000136588, 201801300040150000242399, 201801300040150000293800, 201801300040150000293801, 201801290040150000128792, 201801300040150000367067, 201801300040150000367770, 201801300040150000369255, 201801260040150000097789, 0, 0, 201801290040150000145140, 0, 201801290040150000145184, 201801290040150000145190, 201801290040150000145198, 201801290040150000145206, 201801290040150000145214, 201801290040150000145222, 0, 0, 201801290040150000145245, 201801290040150000145254, 201801290040150000145263, 201801290040150000145271, 201801290040150000145278, 201801290040150000145286, 201801290040150000145297, 201801290040150000145309, 201801290040150000145318, 201801290040150000145327, 201801290040150000149263, 201801290040150000149264, 201801300040150000433569, 201801290040150000156348, 201801290040150000161046, 201801290040150000161050, 201801290040150000165445, 0, 201801290040150000165456, 201801290040150000165472, 0, 0, 201801290040150000165496, 0, 0, 201801290040150000165520, 0, 0, 0, 201801290040150000165556, 0, 201801260040150000129418]
```

Visually, they don't look different.  When i print out the value and dtype:

```
print "bdf: {}, type {}".format(bdf['refid'][0], bdf['refid'].dtype)
print "cdf: {}, type {}".format(cdf['refid'][0], cdf['refid'].dtype)
```

I get:

```
bdf: 201801300040150000014217, type object
cdf: 201801300040150000014217, type object
```

So why would assert_frame_equal() say that they're different, when their values and dtypes are the same? As an observation, there are 200+ columns in these two tables and all of them are also dtype=object, yet i didn't get any comparison errors for those columns.

Comment: Another observation - with a different dataset for cdf and bdf, whenever the values in the series is 0, assert_frame_equal saw them as being equal.

Comment: You might want to compare the repr() and type() of each side as well, just to double-check. My gut feeling is that the 201801300040150000014217 from each side is really an object, and they are different objects with the same string representation. Try bdf['refid'][0] == cdf['refid'][0].

Comment: Can you please follow up with further details? Else this should be closed as "Needs debugging details". Also, you haven't provided reproducible data (not an [mcve]).